# UTF-8 characters in Oracle

Tags: oracle, encoding, utf-8, plsql, plsqldeveloper

**I want to insert UTF-8 characters in Oracle 12 database using INSERT statement.** I'm using PL/SQL Developer Tool (version 8).

When I run this INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES ('ტექსტი');
```

and then run the SELECT statement

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table
```

it returns question marsk

```
??????
```

But when I insert my UTF-8 text manually (using copy & paste) into the table and then run the same SELECT statement it returns data correctly

```
ტესქტი
```

**Should I run any command before inserting UTF-8 character using insert statement?**

Comment: Please run `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%SET%';` and append a result of this query to your question. I guess that `INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES (N'ტექსტი');` shoud give a result you want (just add a prefix N before text literal).

Answer (score 9):

Prefix your string literal with `n` as in

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES (n'ტექსტი');
```

That will tell your Oracle DB that the incoming value is of `nvarchar2` data type.